# Difference between the static and instance sides of classes

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to understand interface topic in Typescript 
when I came across **Class type**, I got this code from [official docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number);
}

class Clock implements ClockConstructor {
    currentTime: Date;
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

I can understand that `Clock` has no match for the signature  `new (hour: number, minute: number);` that's why we get an error there.

But in docs the explaination is something which I am unable to understand. It goes in this way :

> This is because when a class implements an interface, only the instance side of the class is checked. Since the constructor sits in the static side, it is not included in this check.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The interface declares the method/members that the instances have, and not what the implementing class has.

For example check the [Array](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1108) and [ArrayConstructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1243) declarations:

```
interface Array<T> {
    length: number;
    toString(): string;
    toLocaleString(): string;
    push(...items: T[]): number;
    pop(): T | undefined;
    ...
    [n: number]: T;
}

interface ArrayConstructor {
    new (arrayLength?: number): any[];
    new <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    new <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
    (arrayLength?: number): any[];
    <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
    isArray(arg: any): arg is Array<any>;
    readonly prototype: Array<any>;
}
```

As you can see, the `Array` has method/members which exist on any instance of array:

```
let a = [];
a.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(a.length);
```

But the `ArrayConstructor` has the members/methods which exist on the `Array` itself:

```
console.log(Array. prototype);
console.log(Array.isArray(9));
```

The constructors are part of the "static" part which is why they are declared in the `ArrayConstructor`.
If you declare a constructor on an interface for example you'll have a problem implementing that interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    constructor();
    getName(): string;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    constructor() {}

    getName() { return "name" };
}
```

Error:

> Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements interface 'MyInterface'. Types
>   of property 'constructor' are incompatible. Type 'Function' is not
>   assignable to type '() => void'. Type 'Function' provides no match for
>   the signature '(): any'.

Answer (score 5):

Before you can get an instance you need to use the static side, the `constructor`, to get an instance. You don't need `new` in your interface anyway, your class is typed itself so typescript knows whatever arguments it has to pass along the constructor.

You can make benefits of an interface with type `new` if you want to pass a `function` or `class` that has to meet certain constructor requirements before it can be instantiated.

```
interface IFoo {
   new(title: string);
}

function MyFunction(ctor: IFoo, title:string) {
   return new ctor(title);
}

class MyClass {
   constructor(public title: string) {}
}

class MySecondClass {
   constructor(public title: string) {}
}

var myClass = MyFunction(MyClass, 'title');
var mySecondClass = MyFunction(MySecondClass, 'title');

console.log(myClass.title, mySecondClass.title);
```

In fact, a TypeScript class is a regular function in JavaScript which is static when you don't use `new` in front of it. This is were the docs are referring to.

```
// static side
function Person() {

}

Person.SayHi = function () {
  return 'Hello';
}

console.log(Person.SayHi()); // static function..

var person = new Person() // instance side
```

[See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38026080/3891533)