# What is exactly the 'static side' and the 'instance side' in typescript?

Tags: typescript

There is a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362690/difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes), but there is no direct answer to what *static side* and *instance side* are referred to in the documentation.

As i vaguely understand, the *static side* is a constructor and *instance side* is everything else?

An example from [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
    tick(): void;
}

function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
    return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

What is *static side* and *instance side* in this example? Why is a need to use such pattern?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Naming in computer science is notoriously difficult.

In TypeScript, we generally use the same name to refer to the *constructor* of a class (which is a value that exists at runtime), and as the type of the *instances* of the class (which only exists at design time and is not emitted to JavaScript).

So in

```
class Foo { } 
const foo: Foo = new Foo();
```

there is a class constructor named `Foo`, which can be used to construct class instances whose type we call `Foo`.

This is a bit like using the term "Lego" to refer both to the company that manufactures plastic construction toys, and to the construction toys themselves.  Or like "Toyota" as the name of a company and the name of the vehicles that they make.  We say "Toyota makes and sells Toyota vehicles" or "Lego makes and sells Lego construction toys" without misunderstanding, but the analogous "`Foo` constructs `Foo` instances" might be confusing.  So be it, I guess.

---

When we talk about a class, we might be talking about its *static* aspects, which pertain to the constructor (generally singular, "**the** constructor", because there's just one of them, which is the same for all instances), or we might be talking be talking about its *instance* aspects, which pertain to the instances of the class (generally plural, "instance**s**", because the single constructor can make many instances, each of which has possibly different state or properties from others).

From the type system's standpoint, the type `Foo` corresponds to the shape of the instance side.  To get the type of the static side, we can use the [`typeof` type query operator](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/types-from-extraction/#typeof) operating on the constructor value named `Foo`:  `typeof Foo`.  So, `Foo` is the instance side type and `typeof Foo` is the static side type.

Let's augment `Foo` to show how this works:

```
class Foo {

  instanceProp: string;

  constructor(constructorArgument: string) {
    this.instanceProp = constructorArgument;
  }

  instanceMethod(): void {
    console.log("Instance method called on " + this.instanceProp)
  }

  static staticProp: string = "Static Thing";

  static staticMethod(): void {
    console.log("Static method called on " + this.staticProp)
  }

}
```

That's a single class definition, but it has a static side and an instance side.  The static side of `Foo`, that is, things pertaining to its constructor, includes:

- the constructor itself, whose signature is `{new(constructorArgument: string): Foo}`
- the `staticProp` property, whose type is `string`, and
- the `staticMethod` method, whose signature is `{(): void}`.

This type is called `typeof Foo`, but you can actually define your own interface for it if you want, like so:

```
interface StaticSideOfFoo {
  new(constructorArgument: string): Foo;
  staticProp: string;
  staticMethod(): void;
}
```

The instance side of `Foo`, that is, things pertaining to its instances, includes:

- the `instanceProp` property, whose type is `string`, and
- the `instanceMethod` method, whose signature is `{(): void}`.

This type is called `Foo`, and you can define your own interface for this also:

```
interface InstanceSideOfFoo {
  instanceProp: string;
  instanceMethod(): void;
}
```

---

Let's make sure we understand the difference:

```
const foo1 = new Foo("Number 1");
console.log(foo1.instanceProp); // Number 1
foo1.instanceMethod(); // Instance method called on Number 1

const foo2 = new Foo("Number 2");
console.log(foo2.instanceProp); // Number 2
foo2.instanceMethod(); // Instance method called on Number 2

console.log(Foo.staticProp); // Static Thing
Foo.staticMethod(); // Static method called on Static Thing
```

Note that `foo1` and `foo2` have no direct access to the constructor signature or to `staticProp` or `staticMethod`:

```
new foo1("oops"); // error!
foo1.staticProp; // error!
foo1.staticMethod(); // error!
```

and that `Foo` has no direct access to `instanceProp` or `instanceMethod`:

```
Foo.instanceProp; // error!
Foo.instanceMethod(); // error!
```

And the values `foo1` and `foo2` have type `Foo`, which is similar to `InstanceSideOfFoo`, whereas the value `Foo` has type `typeof Foo`, which is similar to `StaticSideOfFoo`.  We can verify that here:

```
const instanceSideOfFoo: InstanceSideOfFoo = foo1; // okay
const instanceSideOfFooOops: InstanceSideOfFoo = Foo; // error!

const staticSideOfFoo: StaticSideOfFoo = Foo; // okay
const staticSideOfFooOops: StaticSideOfFoo = foo1; // error!
```

---

It helps to be able to talk about these different sides because they have different shapes and different uses.  If you want to make a function that accepts the `Foo` constructor, you want to talk about `typeof Foo` or `StaticSideOfFoo` or `new (x: string)=>Foo`, whereas if you want to make a function that accepts an instance of `Foo`, you want to talk about `Foo` or `InstanceSideOfFoo` or `{instanceProp: string}`, etc.

Without such a distinction you might end up trying to buy the Lego corporation for your children or becoming a shareholder in a 1997 Toyota Camry.  Or maybe not, but the analogous mistakes in TypeScript would be too easy to make.  What can I say, naming things is tough.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=37&pc=32#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrrQJYDsIBcwdgBTABQCd4AHALmgItwHMBudTYePfCgV2D54FABRce-QcICCFZnwC2JHPnqMWAShQZM0fAAssEAHS4CRUpRrQAvNHGMBQirPlKV7TAF8O2HhZIAWRIDeAATEQ16ADd4LDDtXXtuCHgQEmMQeGYRACIASX9iEmglUITgMBB0hO5oXOgAaj1DEzNCYqtqDR0fHXN8LGAGQkHgLrVeFlt6gGVRoegAFUMcZlz2foXhgaHg8siYuIS0JIc0jKyc3PmwMdKQ-XD7KproOobmgyNjXfGqbq9dB9Bz4aAAM0QAEYZjgSAB3OCIPIAOUUACMSBRoFDchp2Od0plsiJIfAoaYipYAfjoAB6OnQNEKTHYqGoMkU9oBfZPCK0hnQQrmYoPcovaokWo4JkYrE49CgiGIABMsIRSPgqLl2JVeIJKQuxJyZJVlJF1JoAsZzNZ0BVHNV5o6pF54UirHpjOFLpKZT5EredVt8odqEJlxJCHgv22XWt0Fu9xWLFQ0djdz2j3dCaTi39z0qkulie2y1WzHQcMRnLyiGoEH1XugWKoFAAhI7yRmxl1PYLW8JO5ye1mDgnBx30OnuZ0Af3GZPOzOqUFs-yFy2KG3O6hcPgseCwKRS5ngLN4iQAPLg6OJaDVsQpXhOGRyRTKVQjJhrKKazwjGeEzfiwAF-G6-JHPE7B9Puh7HiUPoBBeYTXreiD3rOlp0CBawAVha7jlBYQwYqz5+BaJAoWh0b0EhxTUTed52Jym7wAA1mAACe4bkQRjHofAV40BAdGrgJzH-s2S5kTwgFjBJiD0Hm56XkxGF2NGbGcTxSp-IpQkicp2wGTMrHSduQ7oNZ1lAA)