# Why is this type not considered Newable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
export class Thing{
    name: string = "dunno"
}

export interface IMakeThing<T extends new (...args: any) => any>{
    value: T
}

const owner = new Thing();

const test:  IMakeThing<Thing> = {
    value: new Thing
};
```

It complains when using the Thing as a generic param on IMakeThing.  But I am not sure why as the generic constraint asks for a constructor function.

Playground link here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictBindCallApply=false&target=1&module=1&ts=4.1.3&ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQGMA2BDAzlpAVACwEsA7AcwG9QkakSMBbMALiSwTlLKQF4kAiACYBXEiRj9QAX1ChIsRElIIwcAGYYUYJAEkAshgDWYQlwA8eJJBUlBuEmADuSABQA6DxjhksrDCQBPAEpeAD4kfwDQqhBaJAA3DDRhFnxpWRAUGBJ2JBhHBzheOid8YnIXIIBuDKyc5BV2Vl0DY1NyC3KycL4YuMTk1IdndrJpKqA

Comment: Because the type named `Thing` refers to the instance type, while the value named `Thing` refers to the constructor, whose type is not `Thing` but `typeof Thing` which is more like `new() => Thing`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399613/what-is-exactly-the-static-side-and-the-instance-side-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, class types are the type of the class objects, and the type of the actual class (the constructor) is `typeof Class`. So, in this case, you'd have to use `IMakeThing<typeof Thing>`, not `IMakeThing<Thing>`. You have another issue where `value` will then have to be the actual class object, so you could make a `ConstructedType` utility type that extracts the type constructed and uses that for the type of `value`:

```
export class Thing{
    name: string = "dunno"
}

type ConstructedType<T extends new (...args: any) => any>
    = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;

export interface IMakeThing<T extends new (...args: any) => any>{
    value: ConstructedType<T>
}

const owner = new Thing();

const test:  IMakeThing<typeof Thing> = {
    value: new Thing
};
```

Or just use the much prettier approach of just using the object type from the beginning since you don't need the constructor type:

```
export class Thing{
    name: string = "dunno"
}

export interface IMakeThing<T>{
    value: T
}

const owner = new Thing();

const test:  IMakeThing<Thing> = {
    value: new Thing
};
```

If you actually mean to put the constructor function under `value`, then just pass `Thing`, not `new Thing`, since `new Thing` expands to `new Thing()`:

```
export class Thing{
    name: string = "dunno"
}

export interface IMakeThing<T extends new (...args: any) => any>{
    value: T
}

const owner = new Thing();

const test:  IMakeThing<typeof Thing> = {
    value: Thing
};
```